# xml.etree.ElementTree: How to access node with attribute name using python

Tags: python, xml.etree

Need help to find specific "xsd:complexType name= 'Fort'"

I tried:

```
for a in root.findall('xsd:complexType name= 'Fort''):
    print(a.attrib)
```

Above code does not work

Below is the xml:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="Fort">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="register" type="Skipsregister" />
      <xsd:element name="type" type="pstype" />
      <xsd:element name="om" type="aade" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [xml.etree.ElementTree Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):
We initialize a tree, then get the root through tree.getroot().

Then you can do:

```
for child in root:
    if(child.attrib == "Fort"): #or child.tag, depending on what you mean by attribute
        #do whatever you want here
```

Comment: thanks, but also have namespace for ex. 
"targetNamespace='urn:ske:fastsetting:v2' "
how do i find it. Would also like to add 'xsd:complexType' so that it find correct element by using find or findall.

Comment: I found this:
for desc in root.findall(namespacess + 'complexType'):
    print(desc.attrib)
But couldn't add attribute 'Fort' while using above syntax root.findall.

Comment: @AAP just use an if statement for the second one(if i understand you are trying to find attribute 'Fort').

Comment: instead of doing:
for a in root.findall('xsd:complexType name= 'Fort''):
    print(a.attrib)
do for a in root.findall('Fort'):
    print(a.attrib)